# graph that combine bar and line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to reproduce this chart with python ie the unemployment rate with shaded period corresponding with recession period.
I downloaded the 2 series from Fred data base with :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as wb
import datetime as dt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_fred = wb.get_data_fred(['USRECD'], dt.datetime(1969, 12, 31)).asfreq('MS')
data_fred_m = wb.get_data_fred(['UNRATE', ],dt.datetime(1969, 12, 31)) 

data = pd.concat([data_fred,data_fred_m], axis =1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have your data, so generated something on my own. Nevertheless, just look at the plotting part and I propose using patches from matplotlib. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import datetime
#==============================================================================================
# HERE IS THE DATA GENERATION:
def get_rate(dd,ds,decay):
    dt = dd-ds;
    dt = dt.days + dt.seconds/86400
    if dt<0: return 0.0
    val = np.exp(-dt/decay)
    return val
# ----------------------------
# let us generate random data:
d0 = datetime.datetime(1950,1,1)
ndays = (datetime.datetime.now()-d0).days
dvec = [d0+ii*datetime.timedelta(days=1) for ii in range(ndays)]
# ------------------------------------------------------------
unemp = 7.5 + np.random.random(np.size(dvec))*1
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# some recession periods:
recper_start = [datetime.datetime(1955,12,3),datetime.datetime(1970,6,1),datetime.datetime(1981,9,9),datetime.datetime(1999,4,23),datetime.datetime(2020,3,1)]
recper_len = [500,700,300,160,190]
recper_end = [recper_start[ii]+datetime.timedelta(days=recper_len[ii]) for ii in range(len(recper_len))]
# ------------------------------------------------------------
for ii in range(len(recper_len)):
     magnitude = 7.5+10*np.random.random()
     addunemp = [magnitude*get_rate(dval,recper_start[ii],recper_len[ii]) for dval in dvec]
     unemp = unemp + addunemp
# ------------------------------------------------------------
recdict = {'start':recper_start,'end':recper_end}
# ================================================================================================
# HERE IS THE PLOTTING:
datadict = {'date':dvec,'data':unemp}; # data of unemployment
data_a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict);data_a = data_a.set_index('date')
datadict = {'start':recper_start,'end':recper_end};
data_b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict); # data of start and end of recession
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Make a plot:
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5));ax = fig.add_subplot(111);
ax.plot(data_a);
for ir,row in data_b.iterrows():
    # the min-max of rec does not change:
    yy = (np.nanmin(data_a),np.nanmax(data_a))
    # ---------------------------------------------------------
    left, bottom, width, height = (row.start, yy[0], row.end-row.start, np.diff(yy))
    rect=mpatches.Rectangle((left,bottom),width,height,alpha=0.2,fill=True,facecolor="0.25")
    ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.set_ylim(yy);ax.set_xlim(np.min(dvec),np.max(dvec))
plt.savefig('test.png',bbox_inches='tight');plt.show()
```

and here is the result:
[image]
Hope it helps!